# Проверить наличие файла на общем ресурсе

Tags: c++, сеть, файловая-система

Как проверить наличие файла на расшаренном ресурсе?
Если этот ресурс подключен как диск с конкретной буквой, тогда не проблема

```
fs::exists("h:/1.txt")
```

а если ресурс не подкючен как диск, тогда его либо нужно подключить средствами С++, либо как то проверить без подключения.

```
 fs::exists("/server1/share/1.txt")
```

так не работает.

Comment: Только что набросал, проверил - работает в Windows как в варианте `\\\\server\\path\\file`, так и в варианте `//server/path/file`. Но, замечу, чувствительно к регистру (сервер Linux'овый - может, потому). Вы перед `server1` не пробовали **два** слеша ставить?

Comment: Оба варианта работают. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что правильное указание сервера - с двойной косой чертой.

```
\\\\server\\path\\file
```

или

```
//server/path/file
```

Ну, и не следует пренебрегать регистрами символов в именах путей/файлов.